# Python string formatting returning a Property instead of a string (unicode)?

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error in Django saying `Caught TypeError while rendering: sequence item 1: expected string or Unicode, Property found`. Here is my code:

```
def __unicode__( self ) :
    return "{} : {}".format( self.name, self.location )
```

I even tried

```
def __unicode__( self ) :
    return unicode( "{} : {}".format( self.name, self.location ) )
```

but the same error.

From what I know `"this is x = {}".format( x )` returns a string right? Why is Python saying it's a Property?

Full code:

```
class Item( models.Model ) :
    def __unicode__( self ) :
        return "{} : {}".format( self.name, self.location )

    name       = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )
    comment    = models.TextField( blank = True )
    item_type  = models.ForeignKey( ItemType )
    location   = models.ForeignKey( Location )
    t_created  = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True, verbose_name = 'created' )
    t_modified = models.DateTimeField( auto_now = True, verbose_name = 'modified' )

class Location( models.Model ) :
    def __unicode__( self ) :
        locations = filter( None, [ self.room, self.floor, self.building ] )
        locations.append( self.prop )

        return ", ".join( locations ) # This will look in the form of like "room, floor, building, property"

    comment    = models.TextField( blank = True )
    room       = models.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
    floor      = models.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
    building   = models.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
    prop       = models.ForeignKey( Property )
    t_created  = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True, verbose_name = 'created' )
    t_modified = models.DateTimeField( auto_now = True, verbose_name = 'modified' )

class Property( models.Model ) :
    def __unicode__( self ) :
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )
```

Comment: Looks like it's saying `self.name` is something it can't turn into a string. Could you show how `self.name` is defined?

Comment: @hobbes3: That is obviously *not* the full code (most importantly, the module `models` is missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Property` isn't referring to a Python property, but to your `Property` class. What's probably happening is this:

1. `Item.__unicode__` gets called.
2. It grabs `self.name` and `self.location`.
3. `self.name` returns a unicode string from its `__unicode__` method.
4. `self.location` is a foreign key, so `Location.__unicode__` gets called.
5. That gets `self.room`, `self.floor`, and `self.building`, which all have `__unicode__` methods that return unicode strings.
6. `filter` sees that these strings are all empty, so `locations` is set to `[]`.
7. `self.prop`, which is a `Property`, gets appended to `locations`.
8. `", ".join( locations )` Throws a `TypeError` because a `Property` isn't a string.
9. the `str.format` call in `Item.__unicode__` catches that exception and throws its own, which is what you see.

Solution: change

```
locations.append( self.prop )
```

to

```
locations.append( unicode(self.prop) )
```

Moral: `str.format` calls `str()` on its arguments, but `str.join` does not.

Comment: Great explanation! I am a little confused about one part though. If you say that `self.prop` calls `Property.__unicode__`, then isn't `Property.__unicode__` also a return a unicode string since it just returns `self.name`? Why do I need to do `unicode( self.prop )`? I'm assuming I always have to do that with a `ForeignKey`, but a little clarification would be nice :-).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?:

```
def __unicode__( self ):
    return "{name}: {location}".format(name=self.name, location=self.location)
```

or

```
def __unicode__( self ):
    return "{0}: {1}".format(self.name, self.location)
```

or

```
def __unicode__( self ):
    return "%s: %s" % (self.name, self.location)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: None of those have any real semantic difference from his code, so if the behavior changed, it would be due to a bug in python.